# Node error: connect ETIMEDOUT when trying to access route /setup

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm following this tutorial guide here on [Authenticate with NodeJs and JSON web tokens.](https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens)

I'm created my **server.js**, **config.js**, and **user model**.

My app ran fine on `localhost:3333` *(my 8080 never works)*. Then I added the `/setup` route to create a user.

After going to /setup the app looked like it hung for awhile, then it threw this error:

[image]

My full server.js file

```
// require packages
// ===================================================================
var express    = require('express');
var app        = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan     = require('morgan');
var mongoose   = require('mongoose');
var jwt        = require('jsonwebtoken');  // used to create, sign, and verify tokens
var config     = require('./config');      // get our config file
var User       = require('./models/user'); // get our mongoose model


// configuration
// ===================================================================
var port = process.env.PORT || 3333;   // used to create, sign, and verify tokens
mongoose.connect(config.database);     // connect to database
app.set('superSecret', config.secret); // secret variable

// use body parser so we can get info from POST and/or URL parameters
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// use morgan to log requests to the console
app.use(morgan('dev'));


// routes
// ===================================================================

// basic route
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello! The API is at http://localhost:' + port + '/api');
});

app.get('/setup', function(req, res) {

    // create a sample user
    var nick = new User({
      name: 'Nick Cerminara',
      password: 'password',
      admin: true
    });

    // save the sample user
    nick.save(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('User saved successfully');
      res.json({ success: true });
    });
});

// API ROUTES -------------------
// we'll get to these in a second


// start the server
// ===================================================================
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens at http://localhost:' + port);
```

My full config file:

```
module.exports = {
    'secret'   : 'ilovescotchyscotch',
    'database' : 'mongodb://noder:noderauth&54;proximus.modulusmongo.net:27017/so9pojyN'
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like database is not available. Why are you trying to use database given in the tutorial? You can either register your own database as given tutorial or try to have it on your own machine for the testing purpose.

Comment: ah thanks... figured they had it hooked up, I guess I'll look into Mongolabs for a free Mongo host